# How to execute selenium tests after 15 minutes of File Uploading in Jsch?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, jsch

My application reads a file to SFTP folder, I need to test that uploaded file in UI. But once I upload a file through SFTP, UI will display that uploaded file after 15 mins only.
I have automated uploading a file through Jsch library, now I need to execute my selenium tests after 15 minutes of file processing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: sleep for 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

try the below code . which will hold the execution of test method for 900000 ms. ie, 15 min

```
@Test
public void sampleTest() throws InterruptedException{
Thread.sleep(900000);
.............
.............

}
```